# How to transfer data between different web applications

Tags: asp.net

I have multiple web application in a single solution. It's not possible to use sessions to transfer data between pages of these applications. How can I do this in a secure manner?
Thanks.

Comment: can you provide the full structure of your project also the info of the and the connection between the projects

Comment: I have separated the tasks between projects. The main project named Interface has the other projects references. Now i need to have relation between these project by passing some parameters. Clearly these projects are also separate in IIS.

Comment: Are your project n-tire or n-layer ?

Comment: My projects are n-layer. But these projects I'm talking about, have the same level.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your `structure` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answers.
After more research I found Single sing on (SSO) to solve the problem. 
Read the article about "Architectural approach of a domain independent Single Sign On implementation for ASP.NET applications." here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429166/Basics-of-Single-Sign-on-SSO